# Is it possible to read from usb webcam to gpu memory directly

Tags: opencv, cuda

I am doing CUDA with OpenCV to process livestream from a usb webcam. currently I am doing something like this:

```
cv::videoCapture cap(0);
cv::Mat h_frame;
while(cap.read(h_frame)){
    cv::cuda::gpuMat d_frame(h_frame);
    //process d_frame;
}
```

Is it possible to get rid of `h_frame` and directly read to `d_frame` :

```
//Imaginary code
cv::cuda::gpuVideoCapture cap(0);
cv::cuda::gpuMat d_frame;
while(cap.read(d_frame)){
    //process d_frame;
}
```

Or even using CUDA directly. I mean like reading the camera output as stream of bytes (directly to the GPU) then acquiring it by `gpuMat` in somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible at this time.

You need to use whatever method you wish to capture the USB data to system memory.  From there you can transfer from system memory to GPU memory.